# Undeclared identifier soAllDirectories

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm trying to use the TDirectory.GetFiles function, but when I add a TSearchOptions third parameter to force a recursive search the compiler raises an error saying that soAllDirectories has not been declared.

```
uses System.IOutils,
     System.Types;

procedure TfrmConversio.btnConversioClick(Sender: TObject);
var FilesPas: TStringDynArray;
begin
  FilesPas := TDirectory.GetFiles('C:\Project', '*.pas', soAllDirectories);
  ProgressBar1.Max := Length(FilesPas);
end;
```

What am I doing wrong ?. I can see that constant in System.IOUtils.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to write

```
TDirectory.GetFiles('C:\Project', '*.pas', TSearchOption.soAllDirectories);
```

The reason is that the compiler directive [`{$SCOPEDENUMS ON}`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Scoped_Enums_(Delphi)) is found before the definition of the `TSearchOption` type. This means precisely that you need to qualify the enumeration's constants with the type name.

From the documentation:

> The **$SCOPEDENUMS** directive enables or disables the use of scoped enumerations in Delphi code. More specifically, $SCOPEDENUMS affects only definitions of new enumerations, and only controls the addition of the enumeration's value symbols to the global scope.
>
> In the **{$SCOPEDENUMS ON}** state, enumerations are scoped, and enum values are not added to the global scope. To specify a member of a scoped enum, you must include the type of the enum.

Comment: Bravo.  I wonder how difficult it would have been for the compiler to mention the state of SCOPEDENUMS in the 'not declared' message?  Not very, I expect...

Comment: It would be even nicer if the compiler were smart enough to recognize that the 3rd parameter is a `TSearchOption` and automatically search for `TSearchOption.soAllDirectories` if it can't find `soAllDirectories` by itself.